# error C1189: #error : This file requires _WIN32_WINNT to be #defined at least to 0x0500. Value 0x0501 or higher is recommended

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I create MFC project in VS2010(windows xp). And i take this error:

```
error C1189: #error : This file requires _WIN32_WINNT to be #defined at least to 0x0500. Value 0x0501 or higher is recommended.
```

if I added in `afxcomctl32.h`: `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501`, i take 60+ errors. 
In project i dont added anything. Use such as Visual Studio created.
What i need to do with this?

Comment: Have you tried including "Windows.h" instead? Or first?

Comment: What version(s) of Windows do you actually need to support?

Comment: if I include windows.h in stdafx.h, i have the same error.

Comment: Windows XP SP3, Windows XP Embedded

Comment: Is that the only error you're gettting?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

afxcomctl32.h is a wrong place I think, to fix this problem make your stdafx.h looking like this:

```
// Modify the following defines if you have to target a platform prior to the ones specified below.
// Refer to MSDN for the latest info on corresponding values for different platforms.
#ifndef WINVER                // Allow use of features specific to Windows 95 and Windows NT 4 or later.
#define WINVER 0x0501        // Change this to the appropriate value to target Windows 98 and Windows 2000 or later.
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT        // Allow use of features specific to Windows NT 4 or later.
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501        // Change this to the appropriate value to target Windows 98 and Windows 2000 or later.
#endif                        

#ifndef _WIN32_WINDOWS        // Allow use of features specific to Windows 98 or later.
#define _WIN32_WINDOWS 0x0501 // Change this to the appropriate value to target Windows Me or later.
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_IE            // Allow use of features specific to IE 4.0 or later.
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0500    // Change this to the appropriate value to target IE 5.0 or later.
#endif
```

Comment: Sure you have pasted this on the very first place in stdafx.h?

Comment: Works for me! thanks @duDE! (now, that's is an affirmative username!)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to the TOP of your StdAfx.h file:

```
#include <sdkddkver.h>
```

In my application, I'm defining

```
_WIN32_WINNT=_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP
```

At first I had the same problem.  I discovered that because when you use MFC, you're not allowed to include windows.h, _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP *is never defined* and so _WIN32_WINNT didn't have a valid value.  By including the header that windows.h uses to define those values (sdkddkver.h), suddenly everything works!

Blech.  I hate programming for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to modify afxcomctl32.h. You just need to include Windows.h before this file.

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. The fact was that the file `atmcore.h` was different from the standart in VS2010.