# This file requires _WIN32_WINNT to be #defined at least to 0x0403. Value 0x0501 or higher is recommended

Tags: c++, .net, c, visual-studio-2010

I have got a project which was built using older version(8) of Visual Studio and i upgraded to Visual Studio 2010 on 32 bit windows 7 operating system.Now i am trying to built the application again and it is giving me error in my .h file like..

```
Error   1   error C1189: #error :  This file requires _WIN32_WINNT to be #defined at least to 0x0403. Value 0x0501 or higher is recommended.    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlcore.h   35  1   Phone
```

The entire project is built on c, c++ and some external .dll's.I tried to search the solution on the web but not succeded to sort it out as i am very new to c and C++ technology..
Please help me to get it done.Thanks..

Update

I am getting error at `altcore.h` file of my application at following line:

```
#if _WIN32_WINNT < 0x0403
#error This file requires _WIN32_WINNT to be #defined at least to 0x0403.     Value 0x0501 or higher is recommended.
#endif
```

Comment: Does it give you any information on what part of your code is triggering the build failure? If so, edit and add that to your post. Also put what version you upgraded *from* as well.

Comment: @Will Yes, It is giving me error at .h file of my application where `#if _WIN32_WINNT < 0x0403
#error This file requires _WIN32_WINNT to be #defined at least to 0x0403. Value 0x0501 or higher is recommended.
#endif` at this condition and line

Comment: if you can, try to create a new project in VS2010 and copy/paste your source files instead of migrating the old project.

Comment: @JoëlHecht Thanks for the suggestion but as it is a big project with lot of class and namespace dependency so it is not possible to create it new successfully...

Comment: Weak on Visual C, but can you not `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501` in some root header file?

Comment: Ah, here we go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643962/error-c1189-error-this-file-requires-win32-winnt-to-be-defined-at-least-to Knew someone had to have asked this before.